# Traveling Salesman with exceptions

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete, hamiltonian-path

Assume a regular TSP problem with *n* cities. However, in this particular problem, we do not have to visit all the *n* cities, only a specific subset of them, *m*, where *m<=n*. The cities in *n* but not in *m* don't need to be visited, but they might if the path *m1->m2* is larger than *m1->n1->m2* for example.

Is this problem still NP-hard ? If yes, to which problem can it be reduced to or what proof could be used to show that it's still NP-hard?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** *m* >= *3*. We have at least an starting city, an ending city and *m-2* cities in between that must be visited.

Comment: How are $m,n$ related?

Comment: If m=n is a particular case of your problem then it's trivially NP-hard...

Comment: **m** is a subset of **n**. **m** <= **n**.
If **m=n**, than its the regular TSP. The problem is when **m<n**.

Comment: This is essentially the traveling salesman problem on $m$ cities. It is *exactly* the same as the usual problem on $m$ cities if the distances between cities forms a metric space. Otherwise, we can more or less just find the shortest path between each pair of cities and use that as the distance between them (but this runs into problems too since we shouldn't traverse cities twice). It would certainly seem to be at least as hard as the usual problem on $m$ cities.

Comment: The particularity of stating that *m* is a subset of *n* is that two cities in *m* could not have any path between them in *m*.

Answer (score 1):

This problem, as stated, is too vague to answer.  What is critical is the relationship between $m,n$.  If $m=n$, then this is identical to TSP.  If $m=n-1$ or similar, it is polynomially equivalent to TSP.  If $m=2$, then the problem is polynomial-time: find the shortest path between the two vertices with [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Comment: I see, thanks! In this particular case **m>=3** (We have at least a starting city, an ending city and a city in-between that must be visited.) polynomially equivalent to TSP then, right?

Comment: With any constant $m$ it's still polynomial.  You can use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path between any two vertices of $m$, then do a mini-TSP on those $m$ vertices.  The point of NP-hard is that $n$ is growing to infinity, and we are watching how the algorithm slows down as $n$ does so.